# Are there any hints about Locke's exact location in the World of Ruins?

Tags: final-fantasy-6

I'm watching a first-time playthrough of Final Fantasy VI. The streamer is searching for Locke. He's found Rachel and the old man, but the old man only says, *"Find the treasure, find Locke"* (or something to that effect).

I know where Locke is, but are there any hints that direct the player to his exact location? Or is it to be found by chance?

> [image]
>
>  (Locke is found at Phoenix Cave.)

Extra credit: What would be a good hint to give a player who's getting frustrated, without easily giving it away? (The player has found all other characters, so there's probably no other spoilers to be concerned about.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to head to [Owzer's Mansion](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Owzer%27s_Mansion) to have a hint about where to find the treasure:

> In the World of Ruin, if the player inspects Emperor Gestahl's portrait twice, they receive **the key item Emperor's Letter**, ...

> which hints to the location of the Phoenix Cave.

> This letter tells that the treasure is located in the Star shaped mountains, **which is exactly the shape of the Phoenix Cave (location 17)**

Comment: There's also the guard at the Coliseum that hints about "talking to the Emperor twice" to get his treasure.

Comment: Ah, so that was it. Thanks!